# Show that the cardinality of the preimage is measurable

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is continuous in $\mathbb R$ such that $|\{x:f(x)=y\}|<\infty$ for any $y\in \mathbb R$(where $|\cdots|$ means cardinality). Show that
$$
g(y)=|\{x:f(x)=y\}|
$$ is a measurable function. Moreover, show this is not true if $f$ is only measurable. Please give me some hints. Thanks.

Comment: Is $|\cdot\$ the cardinality or the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @user251257 cardinality

Answer (score 1):

Case 1, $f$ is continuous: Note that if $f$ has a local extremum at $x,$ then $f$ has a strict local extremum at $x.$ This follows from the condition that $f^{-1}(y)$ is finite for all $y.$ Now for any continuous function on $\mathbb {R},$ the set of $x$ such that $f(x)$ is a strict local extreme value is at most countable. So let $C$ denote the set of strict local extreme values of $f.$ Because $C$ is countable, it's enough to show that $g(y)$ is measurable on $\mathbb {R}\setminus C.$

Claim: $g$ is lower-semicontinuous on $\mathbb {R}\setminus C.$ If we show this, it follows that $g$ is measurable on $\mathbb {R}.$ Proof of claim: let $y_0 \in \mathbb {R}\setminus C.$ If $g(y_0) = 0,$ there is nothing to show since $g\ge 0.$ So suppose $g(y_0)= n >0.$ Then there are distinct $x_1, \dots,x_n$ such that $f(x_k) = y_0, k=1,\dots ,n,$ and no $x_k$ gives a local extremum. Choose pairwise disjoint open intervals $I_k$ with $x_k\in I_k, k = 1,\dots , n.$ Then there are $a_k,b_k\in I_k$ with $f(a_k) < y_0 < f(b_k)$ for all $k.$ Let $$M= \min (f(b_1),\dots ,f(b_n), m = \max (f(a_1),\dots ,f(a_n)).$$ By the IVT, $f(I_k)\supset [m,M]$ for each $k.$  This implies $g(y)\ge n=g(y_0)$ for all $y\in[m,M].$ Because $y_0$ is an interior point of $[m,M],$ this gives the desired lower-semicontinuity.

Case 2, $f$ is only measurable: Let $K$ be the Cantor set. Recall $m(K)=0$ and the cardinality of $K$ equals that of $[0,1].$ So there is a bijection $h:K\to [0,1].$ Now $[0,1]$ contains a nonmeasurable set $E.$ Define

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} e^x + 1, x\in \mathbb {R}\setminus K\\ 
h(x), x \in h^{-1}(E)\\
-(e^x+1),x\in K\setminus h^{-1}(E) \end{cases}$$

Then $f$ is measurable. Why? Here we use the completeness of Lebesgue measure: $f$ is obviously measurable off of $K,$ and since $m(K) = 0,$ that's enough. Verify that on $[0,1],$ the associated function $g(y)$ is precisely the characteristic function of $E.$ It follows that $g$ is nonmeasurable.